# MultiThreading with Crystal Reports, VB.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am implementing multithreading to show crystal Reports with Crystal Report Viewer, Done that successfully, but the form loaded is closing automatically, when I did not implement multithreading for the same I did not find any problem. The Code I am calling the reports is

```
objForm.ViewReport("~Path\CrystalReports\" & _ReportName, , _parameters)
objForm.Show()
```

ViewReport Calls a form - frmViewReport which has CrystalReportViewer

Answer (score 1):

Call `objForm.ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`

What is happening is that the current thread that you are opening the `objForm` object on is ending and getting rid of everything on it. Calling `ShowDialog` will cause it to stay active until the Form is closed.

Comment: I tried with ShowDialog, but for the first Thread I am getting Data, not for the second...